# Pre-select option if IonSelect

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

If I have an `IonSelect` component like this one:

```
<IonSelect placeholder={"Days"}>
  <IonSelectOption value="0">0</IonSelectOption>
  <IonSelectOption value="3">3</IonSelectOption>
  <IonSelectOption value="5">5</IonSelectOption>
  <IonSelectOption value="7">7</IonSelectOption>
</IonSelect>
```

And I want for example the option "3" to be selected when the component is loaded, is there any way to acieve that? In vanilla HTML, you can just add the `selected` property to the `option` tag, but that does not seem to work in Ionic/React.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: according to the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select you can set the value attribute on the `IonSelect` to set/bind the selected value

Comment: Thank you. I tried that earlier and it din't work, now it does. Have a nice day!!